# Mini "image composer" in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, web

For a small project, I've to create in html/javascript (no Flash/Silverlight... it has to work on tablet devices) a small "image composer":

The goal is to create an image, and it can be composed of many others, so the goal is to:

- upload images on the server
- have the possibility to add them on the "workspace", resize/rotate/move them
- Same thing with text

The problem is that the application has to be compatible with IE7, so I cannot use html5.

So do you think it's possible? Have you any link/experience in this domain? I've just no idea about how to do this. Is there some library which can do the job(or even help)?

In fact I found a website which has almost exactly what I want: http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/app

How they did this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing a custom script with jquery

Comment: No sorry, it's on an intranet for customers

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see all you need is possibility to apply various transformations to images. You can do it in cross-browser manner using combination of SVG/VML technologies. At first you can try to use raphael library for that. Take a look at [Paper.image](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.image) method. For transformations you can use [Element.rotate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.rotate) and [Element.scale](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.scale).

Comment: I can't see the advantage of this kind of part against some library like jquery which allows to do this directly with div, ... The problem I've with this kind of low level library, is that I don't know how to do the anchor, and how to resize instantly the image